# Correct Usage of OAuth 2.0 Grant Types

Tags: api, rest, security, oauth-2.0, reverse-proxy

In the following we sum up our argumentation for using certain [OAuth 2.0 *grant types*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#page-8) in two scenarios and kindly ask the community to either agree with our argumentation or to identify weaknesses.

The overall goal is to protect an enterprise API using OAuth 2.0. For this use case of OAuth 2.0 we distinguish two scenarios:

- Scenario A: The API is used by an application developed by a third party, e.g. an application available from an app-store that uses our API.
- Scenario B: An in-house developed application which uses the API, e.g. a single-page web-application that uses a *RESTful* API.

We use a Gateway (which embeds a reverse proxy and an OAuth 2.0 client) in order to hide the internal API security mechanism and not to expose the *Access Tokens* to the public. The Gateway handles both dynamic routing and mapping between the sessions on the customer side and the *Access Tokens* on the internal side. Relying on cookie-based session management, allows us to benefit from already established session protection mechanisms and enables *Single-Sign-On* capabilities for different client applications. We use [*JWT Bearer Tokens*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519) to authorize the calls between the Gateway and the APIs.

In both our scenarios, the OAuth 2.0 client is under our control and can thus be considered as [*confidential*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#page-14).

According to our understanding, the two scenarios have different protection requirements:

- Scenario A: The application code is not under our control and may contain malicious components. We thus want to prevent the application from getting hold of any user credentials or *Access Tokens*. Using the [**Authorization Code** *grant type*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#page-24), the Resource Owner authenticates against our platform (redirected to the our OAuth 2.0 authorization server) and grants access to his resources.

[image: Securing APIs from Public Application calls with OAuth 2.0]

- Scenario B: This time the application code is under our control, i.e. we know that the code does not contain malicious functionality. We can therefore trust the application to process user credentials reliably. As a consequence we propose to use the [**Resource Owner Password Credentials** *grant type*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#page-37). In this case the Resource Owner credentials are exchanged for an *Access Token* using a single request without requiring the Resource Owner to approve the access to the resources.

[image: Securing APIs from Homemade Application calls with OAuth 2.0]

In both scenarios, the *JWT Bearer Token* does not leave our platform and is only used between the Gateway and the corresponding APIs, whereas communication to the user agent (typically the browser) uses classical cookie-based session management. As a consequence of this setup we enable session based *Single-Sign-On* capabilities on the user side, whereas we allow stateless API-design as it is required in modern architecture styles such as *REST*.

Answer (score 2):

In a regular OAuth 2.0 scenario, both the Web App and the Mobile App would be OAuth 2.0 clients in their own right. Of course it is possible to do OAuth 2.0 between Gateway and backends as well, but it makes sense to use a standard protocol towards the Web App and Mobile App, especially since the latter is developed by a 3-rd party.

Weirdly enough your reasoning is completely correct and valid for the situation where the Web App and Mobile App are OAuth 2.0 clients. But for the situation where the Private Gateway is the OAuth 2.0 Client in a pure internal scenario, security considerations and standardization are actually less relevant.

So the question is: what type of authentication/authorization do you use for your Web App and Mobile App. Especially for the latter it is interesting to know how the communication between the Mobile App is secured and authenticated. I believe that leg begs for OAuth 2.0. Also the way in which the Web App presents the username password to the Private Gateway, and the way in which a session or token is maintained after that, begs for OAuth 2.0.

(But perhaps the picture is just a mis-representation and the text is what matters here)

Comment: Thanks @hans-z for taking some time to reply. I am sorry if the diagrams were confusing. I updated them and added tubes between the user agents and the gateway to denote the cookie based session to the gateway _hidden_ inside and protected by an `SSL/TLS` tunnel. The arrows of the `OAuth 2.0` flows are intentionally very simplied. The idea here is just to show where we plan to use which of the `OAuth 2.0` _grant types_, not to draw all the requests, this is well explained in the [RFC 6749](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749)

Comment: How do the Apps obtain the session cookie?

Comment: In scenario A: via a redirect to the Authorization Server (triggered by the gateway). In scenario B: this is a good question (since the Gateway's embedded `OAuth 2.0` client is the one which is going to request the `Access Token`. I see two solutions: 1. The gateway as a small login page on which the Resource Owner is asked to communicate his credentials. 2. The Gateway offers a `REST` service which takes the user credentials as parameters. In both cases, the gateway should then use its embedded  `OAuth 2.0` client to ask for the `Access Token` himself and store it as SessionScoped Bean.

Comment: Regarding your previous comments: _... in a regular OAuth2 scenario, both ... would be OAuth 2.0 clients._: According to our understanding RFC 6749 distinguishes "confidential" and "public" clients (clients in the sens of OAuth 2.0 clients). In our scenario we want to implement "confidential" clients, such that access to the resources is only possible using a client under our control.

Comment: _But for situations ..., security considerations and standardisation are actually less relevant._: We do not understand why this should be the case. The setup described above is expected to protect a high security web-application/API using well established cookie-based session management. Therefore very standard for the client. We simply hide him that the Resource APIs he calls are internally protected using `OAuth 2.0`.

Comment: the point of OAuth 2.0 is to externalize user (Resource Owner) authentication from the Client and to transport tokens from/to Clients; that is most useful for 3-rd party clients but in your case you're using it on an internal network only and *not* towards the 3rd-party Client; so my point is: use OAuth 2.0 towards the Apps since that is what it is designed for; the 3rd-party app should not need to see the user credentials

Comment: Third-party apps are covered by our scenario A. In which the app never gets the Resource Owner credentials (since we are using the `Authorization Code` grant type). However, in the case of `internally developed` applications (scenario B), we do no see the need for the `Resource Owner` to grant access to his resources (since the client application as well as the resources are under our control). The decision to either grant or deny  access to a resource to an internally developed application is _internal_ and there is no need to involve the `Resource Owner`.

Comment: In scenario B, we want to use the `OAuth 2.0 JWT Bearer Tokens` to do identity and role propagation. Since we control both the client applications and the resources, we could also use other mechanisms. In order to ensure scalable `RESTful` resource APIs (which can be easily used from both Single-Page-Applications as well as classical web applications or fat-clients), securing the APIs using `OAuth 2.0` internally seems to be the most promising solution.

Comment: does it makes sense to you?

Comment: I don't see why you'd do something proprietary outwards facing and do something standardized inwards facing, but feel free to do so :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81643/discussion-between-jeremie-and-hans-z).